# PHP: Uploading and renaming image

Tags: php, forms, upload

Im using a script to upload and rename a file.
The form looks like this.

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="text" name="shortlink" placeholder="Shortlink"><br>
<input id="file" name="file" type="file" />
<input id="Submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

The php uploader looks like this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $file_basename = substr($filename, 0, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file extention
    $file_ext = substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file name
    $filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
    $allowed_file_types = array('.doc','.docx','.jpg','.jpeg','.pdf');  

    if (in_array($file_ext,$allowed_file_types) && ($filesize < 20000000000000))
    {   
        // Rename file
        $newfilename = $_POST['shortlink'] . $file_ext;
        if (file_exists("upload/" . $newfilename))
        {
            // file already exists error
            echo "You have already uploaded this file.";
        }
        else
        {       
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $newfilename);
            echo "File uploaded successfully.";     
        }
    }
    elseif (empty($file_basename))
    {   
        // file selection error
        echo "Please select a file to upload.";
    } 
    elseif ($filesize > 20000000000000)
    {   
        // file size error
        echo "The file you are trying to upload is too large.";
    }
    else
    {
        // file type error
        echo "Only these file typs are allowed for upload: " . implode(', ',$allowed_file_types);
        unlink($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    }
}
```

It works perfect when i try to upload simple text files (.txt, .doc, .docx). But when i try to upload any .jpg images it gives no response. The form just clears and thats all. No error message or anything.
Can anybody tell me where the error lays?

Comment: Its works neat for me.

Comment: @marwej , can you tell us what error are you getting ?

Comment: there is one problem first time image uploaded successfully but second time when you upload any same extension file with different name then it gives error that "you have already uploaded this file".

Comment: Just figured out that it works great with smaller files. But when i try to upload bigger images >5mb i get the same problem.

Comment: And i dont get any error message. The form just clears and nothing happens.

Comment: Increase `upload_max_filesize` in your **php.ini file**

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope this will work :-

```html
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$allowedSize=2;//MB
$allowedFileSize=$allowedSize*1024*1024;//Bytes
$allowedExt=array('pdf','doc','docx');
$extnsn=implode(',' , $allowedExt);
if($_FILES['file']['error']==0)
{
if($_FILES['file']['size']<=$allowedFileSize)
 {
 $p_image=$_FILES['file']['name'];
 
$p_image=date('ymdHis').'_'.uniqid().'_'.$p_image;
 
$fileInfoArray=pathinfo($p_image);
$fileExt = $fileInfoArray['extension'];
 
 if(in_array($fileExt,$allowedExt)) {
        $src = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $dest = "uploads/legal-internship/$p_image";
   $ismoved = move_uploaded_file($src,$dest);  
        
    $_POST['image'] = $p_image;
          

        } else {
          echo "<br>Please upload file with valid extension ($extnsn).PLease Try Again ";
        }
      } else {
        echo "Please upload file with MAX $allowedSize MB";
      }
    } else {
      echo "Error while Uploading File Size Exceed to 2MB";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Side note: "20000000000000" = 20 Terabytes. Seems like quite a large image...

Comment: Yea.. That was just to be shure ;)

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

My wamp server was the limit. Found a guide here which solved the problem.
http://rj45tech.com/increasing_php_memory_limit_and_file_upload_size_wamp